# Access event information inside Full Calendar List View

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using **Full Calendar v3**

In the list view of Full Calendar, I want to display event **address** also, which I am passing in the event JSON along with other event information like **start**, **end** etc.
By default list view only shows me the **title** of the event, how can I add an extra column to show the address of event also, and make that address **clickable** to open some sort of map associated with that address.

What I tried is, to add `address` as `eventAddress` data attribute in `title`, with eventRender function.

```
        eventRender: function(event, el) {
                    $el.find('.fc-title').attr( "data-eventAddress", event.address);
                },
```

and tried to access it in `viewRender` or `eventAfterAllRender`, but I am unable to figure out how to use it in below lines (where the address is written).

```
 viewRender: function(view, element) {
  element.find(".fc-list-item-title").after("<td>"+address+"</td>");
  element.find('.fc-list-heading .fc-widget-header').after('<td class=\"fc-widget-header\" colspan=\"1\"></td>');
}
```

Note: I only want this modification in ListView and other views should not get affected.

**If anybody knows how to use event information in ListView mode and how to manipulate the list, please help me.**

Comment: Anyway you can add a cell to the list item fairly easily: `eventRender: function (eventInfo, element, view) {
      element.append("<td>" + eventInfo.address + "</td>");
    }`. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGwXaPg
` . if you want to make it clickable, use a hyperlink in the HTML.

Comment: @ADyson : Its an old project sir, many functions of it are already in use, so with a limited time, can not upgrade it to the new version, so has to stick with the old v3.